# How git lfs work ? Do I need to do "git add"?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I can't understand how git lfs works.  Do I need to maintain LFS store ? 
Do I need to do "git lfs track *.dat" every time ?
Do I need also do "git add *.dat" every time ?

Comment: I've never used GIT Large File Storage, but it seems you have to add `git lfs track *.dat` in `.gitattributes`

Comment: I know. My question is: Do you I need also do git add file.dat ? git lfs need to do only once time ? @RonvanderHeijden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do I need to maintain LFS store?

   No, the LFS store is maintained by the Git server.
2. Do I need to do `git lfs track *.dat` every time?

   No, when you execute `git lfs track *.dat`, a `.gitattributes` file with the following content is created:

   ```
    *.dat filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
   ```

   From now on every .dat file you create will be stored in the Git LFS. Do not forget to also add/commit/push the .gitattributes file so you never will need to recreate it again, in a case you (or someone else) needs to create the local repository.
3. Do I need also do `git add *.dat` every time?

   Yes, the `git add` command continues to work the same way.

To learn more about Git LFS and understand the issue it solves, see the [What is Git LFS?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gaTargV5BY) video.

Comment: Can you explain how it works ? I can't understand why need to separate repository to LFS store and bitbucket ? what is goal of idea ? @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira

Comment: I updated my answer with a nice video to understand the Git LFS idea.

Comment: I saw it but i don't understand the main idea. How does it save place ?  @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira

Comment: When you clone a Git repository you receive all versions of all files. This can be too much time consuming for binary files. The Git LFS enables to keep binary files in a different place, so when you clone a repository Git LFS will manage to you receive just one version of the binary files saving you a lot of time (and resources).

Comment: The goal of lfs save time of clone only ? what is about of push and pull ? Do I only get pointer to binary file ? @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira

Comment: Just in the clone. No, if you have the Git LFS correctly installed you'll receive the real file not the pointer. But again: just the version needed (accordingly with your Git HEAD) not all versions.

Comment: In simple git I also get needed verstion if I wrote: git clone -b <branch_name> @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira

Comment: You get the needed version AND ALL OTHER VERSIONS!

Comment: Very useful video link! I added it to my references in my answer here: [How to use `git lfs` as a basic user: What is the difference between `git lfs fetch`, `git lfs fetch --all`, `git lfs pull`, and `git lfs checkout`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72610495/4561887)